# OllyDbg, breakpoint log and encoding

Tags: ollydbg

I can set up a breakpoint in OllyDbg and make it log a string in following ways:

- `[esp-4]` - OllyDbg will figure out if it should log a number, a string or whatever
- `STRING [[esp-4]]` - OllyDbg will show a string pointed to by value held in `esp-4`
- `UNICODE [[esp-4]]` - OllyDbg will show an Unicode string pointed to by value held in `esp-4`

However, all of these are useless if I work with Japanese text that is encoded in Shift-JIS format. OllyDBG thinks it's empty text since it contains non-ASCII characters. Is there any way I can log these? Or log all bytes until NULL byte?

Comment: What version of OllyDbg are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.01.

Answer (score 1):

What I got is that your problem is with showing non-ASCII chars... try these solutions:

- In OllyDBG: Options — Debugging Options — Strings - tick "Allow diacritical symbols in strings".
- Use "Ultra String Reference" plugin.
- Try OllyICE or OllySharp.

Similar issue (use google translate): http://www.at4re.com/f/showthread.php?11337

Comment: OllyDBG can either log Unicode or ASCII strings, and I need to log multibyte strings. The information I log is misinterpreted, not mispresented. So unfortunately the things you posted do not help much - changing any encoding-related settings doesn't change anything, the plugin does something else, and OllyICE seems to be based on 1.10 which has poor Unicode support.